# How to calculate arithmetic percentage value using set_fact in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am writing a ansible playbook to calculate the advisory_limit_size which is 80% of the hard_limit_size if the unit is in GB.

```
- name: isi_increase_quota
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    new_hard_limit_size:
    new_advisory_limit_size:


  tasks:
    - name: Advisory limit size if cap unit is GB
      set_fact:
         new_advisory_limit_size: "{{ (new_hard_limit_size*0.8)|int }}"
      when: ( unit =="GB" )

    - name: Print
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ new_hard_limit_size }}"
          - "{{ new_advisory_limit_size }}"
```

I am using extra vars to pass the values for now

```
 ansible-playbook isi_increase_quota_v1.yml -e "unit==GB new_hard_limit_size=2"
```

My output is

```
(ansible-3) [*****@****** ansiblecode]$ ansible-playbook isi_increase_quota_v1.yml -e "unit==GB new_hard_limit_size=2"
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [isi_increase_quota] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Advisory limit size if cap unit is GB] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Print] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "2",
        null
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am looking for **new_advisory_limit_size = 1.6** but i am getting **null**...
I am not sure where i am going wrong. Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues

1. ansible invocation has a typo `unit==GB` should be `unit=GB`. Notice double *==* instead of single *=*.
2. *set_fact* should be `new_advisory_limit_size: "{{ new_hard_limit_size | float * 0.8 }}"`.

I see following output post the changes

```
PLAY [isi_increase_quota] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Advisory limit size if cap unit is GB] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "2",
        "1.6"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for getting a `null` value is because the `set_fact` task was skipped, and the value that was assigned in the `vars:` section remains.

This is because you are passing extra-vars with `==`, i.e. `unit==GB`.

Another issue could be that you are converting the value of `new_advisory_limit_size` to `int` *after* the calculation, which will convert float (`1.6`) to integer. The `int` filter should be applied on the `new_hard_limit_size` input (if required).

Example:

```yaml
    - name: Advisory limit size if cap unit is GB
      set_fact:
        new_advisory_limit_size: "{{ new_hard_limit_size | int * 0.8 }}"
      when: unit == "DB"

    - name: show new_advisory_limit_size
      debug:
        var: new_advisory_limit_size
```

When running the playbook, pass `-e "unit=GB"` and it should work as expected.